# Let $f:\mathbb [0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be defined by $f(x)=\frac{x}{1-e^{-x}}$ if $x>0$ and $f(0)=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I was thinking about the problem that says:

Let $f:\mathbb [0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be defined by 
 $f(x)=\frac{x}{1-e^{-x}}$ if $x>0$ and $f(0)=0$.

Then the function is

> (a)continuous at $x=0,$
>   (b)bounded,
>   (c)increasing,
>   (d)zero for at least one $x>0.$

Here is my attempts:

For $x>0,f(x)=\frac{x}{1-e^{-x}}=\frac{1}{1-x/2!+x^{2}/3!-...}=\frac{1}{1-p},where    p=x/2!-x^{2}/3!+...$ and hence $f(x)=(1-p)^{-1}=1+p+p^{2}+p^{3}+p^{4}+p^{5}+.....$ which shows that f is not bounded. From the series representations, it appears that f is increasing. I can also show that f is not continuous at $x=0.$ So, I can eliminate the choices $(a), (b)$. So the answer should be $(c)$.Since $f(x) \neq 0$ for any $x>0$.,option $(d)$ also is not possible. Am I going in the right direction? Please help. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: For the first, the calculation is not quite right. I would rather say use L'Hospital's Rule to show that the limit as $x$ approaches $0$ from the right is $1$.  But series correctly handled is good too.

Comment: The function seems to be continous in 0. It has a removable singulartiy.

Comment: @CBenni: It would be continuous if $f(0)$ had been defined o be $1$.

Comment: @learner: OK, now unbounded. Our function is $\gt x$.

Comment: The fourth option? For the function to be $0$, the top would need to be $0$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes sir. I see that $f(x)=0$ gives $\frac{xe^{x}}{e^{x}-1}=0$ and which gives x=0.So we can not have $f(x)=0$ for at least one $x>0$. Am i right ,sir? So which choice will be correct?

Comment: c) is the only correct choice.  And no sirs, please!

Comment: @AndréNicolas The function isnt even well-defined ^.^ for x=0, we have $0/0$ which is indeterminate, however, the interval is set from $[0,\infty)$. If it were defined from $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=
\begin{cases} \frac{x}{1-e^x} &\mbox{if } x\neq 0 \\
1 & \mbox{else}\end{cases}
$, (a) and (c) are true.
EDIT: nvm, cant read >_<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

a) Use L'Hospital's Rule, or some other method, to show that the limit from the right is $1$.

b) The function is $\gt x$.

c) $e^x\ge 1+x$.

d) Needs no hint.